# Issue in IOS Push Notification - Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using the below code for push notification.

```
public void PushNotificationIOS(string message, string registrationKey)
{

    string deviceID = registrationKey; 
    int port = 2195;
    String hostname = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];//"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    string certPath = string.Empty;
    certPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePath"] + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cer
    String certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(certPath);
    string certPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"];
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    try
    {

        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), certPassword);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)32);
        writer.Write(StringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
        String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":0,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
        byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        writer.Write(b1);
        writer.Flush();
        byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
        sslStream.Write(array);
        sslStream.Flush();
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
    {

        client.Close();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
On Trace, I am getting the below

```
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckThrow(Boolean authSucessCheck)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.get_SecureStream()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer)
```

I tried all the things mentioned in various post but am not able to solve the issue.

Comment: which version of .Net you are using 4.0 or 4.5 or 4.6?

Comment: it is MVC 4.5 framework. Visual studio 2015

Comment: Error removed when I create certificate using private key only. Also, give permission to the folder in which .p12 is lied.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure certificate is valid & is not corrupted. You can regenerate certificate to be dead sure.

Try providing all the options for `SecurityProtocolType` like :

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls, false);
```

`SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` can negotiate Transport layer security 1.1 or downwards too but try all options to be sure.

[image]

For more details on `SecurityProtocolType` refer :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already created new certificate also tried the certificate on iphone itself and notification is working correctly.
I also used the below code.
try{
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
}
catch(exception e)
{
mylog(e.message);
}
try{
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls11, false);
}
catch(exception e)
{
mylog(e.message);
}
try{
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
}
catch(exception e)
{
mylog(e.message);
}
In every catch I got same error.

Comment: Just don't write all variations at same time try one by one. OR Use Pipe symbol...